# How to use table as a column inside .select() in knex.js

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I have a query like this one below:

```
knex('some_table')
.innerJoin('stockcurrent','some_table.id','stockcurrent.id')
.select('id','units',
   knex.raw(`array_to_string(array(select sp.purchaseprice 
        from stockcurrent_part as sp 
        where sp.product = stockcurrent.product 
        and sp.company = ${req.userData.company} 
        and sp.date in (select min(sp2.date)
            from stockcurrent_part as sp2
            where sp2.product = stockcurrent.product
            and sp2.company = ${req.userData.company})
        ),',  ') as cost`))
```

it gives me error in Network but does not specify the error. But when I use values instead of `sp2.product = 19222` and `sp2.company = 18` it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using placeholders so that you don't subject yourself to SQL injection:

```
knex('some_table')
.innerJoin('stockcurrent','some_table.id','stockcurrent.id')
.select('id','units',
   knex.raw(`array_to_string(array(select sp.purchaseprice 
        from stockcurrent_part as sp 
        where sp.product = stockcurrent.product 
        and sp.company = ? 
        and sp.date in (select min(sp2.date)
            from stockcurrent_part as sp2
            where sp2.product = stockcurrent.product
            and sp2.company = ?)
        ),',  ') as cost`),[req.userData.company, req.userData.company])
```